# How to protect a row of data(whole row content not column wise) in an excel using epplus & c#

Tags: c#, epplus

worksheet.Protection.IsProtected = true;
worksheet.ProtectedRanges.Add("editable", new ExcelAddress(2, 1, RowCount1, 3));

but i have to protect few rows of data from editable fields

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Style.Locked property of the ExcelRange

```
// Protect the worksheet
ws.Protection.IsProtected = true; // NOTE: This locks all cells by default

// Make all cells editable
ws.Cells.Style.Locked = false;

// Lock just the first row
ws.Row(1).Style.Locked = true;

// Lock a range of rows
ws.Cells["4:6"].Style.Locked = true;
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, please be sure to to mark it as answered. Thanks.